# Importance of predicates similar to the form $(Ex)(y)R(a_1,...,a_n,x,y)$ where $R$ is general recursive

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, recursion, computability, meta-math

In *Introduction to Metamathematics* (Kleene) there are a few theorems pertaining to predicates of the the form $$(Ex)R(a_1,...a_n,x) \,\,\,\,\,\,(x)(Ey)R(a_1,...a_n,x,y)\,\,\,\,\,\,(Ex)(y)(Ez)R(a_1,...a_n,x,y,z)\,\,\,\,\,\,...$$
$$(x)R(a_1,...a_n,x) \,\,\,\,\,\,(Ex)(y)R(a_1,...a_n,x,y)\,\,\,\,\,\,(x)(Ey)(z)R(a_1,...a_n,x,y,z)\,\,\,\,\,\,...$$
where $R$ is general recursive.
e.g.

> Theorem 35 ($\S72$): The satisfying predicates $P_1,...,P_s$ for F in Theorem 34 [Gödel's Completeness Theorem of pure predicate calculus] can be chosen so that $P_j(a_1,...,a_{n_j}) \equiv (Ex)(y)R_j(a_1,...,a_{n_j},x,y)\equiv (x)(Ey)S_j(a_1,...,a_{n_j},x,y)$ where $R_j$ and $S_j$ are primitive recursive ($j = 1,...,s$).

i.e. For a formula F that is irrefutable in the predicate calculus, there is a satisfying model in the domain of natural numbers such that the predicate letters $P_1,...P_s$ of this model are of the form above.

My question is: Why do we care about theorems like this? Why are number theoretic predicates of this form important?

I would understand the significance of this theorem if we could choose a model so that the predicate letters $P_1,...P_s$ were just general recursive (not $(Ex)(y)R$ where $R$ is general recursive).  This way we would could find a model where the predicates are effectively decidable.   However, predicates of the form above are not necessarily effectively decidable.

Answer (score 1):

This is the [arithmetic hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetical_hierarchy), and the relevant notation ($\Pi^0_n, \Sigma^0_n,\Delta^0_n$) is quite snappy so I'll use it.

There is a tight connection between *syntactic complexity* and *computational complexity*. Specifically:

- A set $X\subseteq\mathbb{N}$ has a $\Sigma^0_n$ definition **if and only if** $X$ is many-one reducible to ${\bf 0^{(n)}}$ (for $\Pi^0_n$, we get many-one reducibility to the *complement* of ${\bf 0^{(n)}}$).
- A set $X\subseteq\mathbb{N}$ has a $\Delta^0_n$ definition (that is, $X$ has a $\Pi^0_n$ definition and $X$ also has a $\Sigma^0_n$ definition) **if and only if** $X$ is Turing-reducible to ${\bf 0^{(n-1)}}$.

(Here the "${\bf a^{(n)}}$" notation denotes the $n$th Turing jump of the degree ${\bf a}$ - and I'm taking ${\bf 0^{(0)}}$ to just be ${\bf 0}$, the degree of the computable sets, for simplicity.) Moreover, these facts relativize - e.g. replacing $\Sigma^0_n$ with $\Sigma^0_n$ *relative to* $A$ and replacing ${\bf 0^{(n)}}$ with $deg(A){\bf ^{(n)}}$. We can add more characterizations, and in particular we have [Shoenfield's limit lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computation_in_the_limit#Limit_lemma) and its extensions.

In particular, results of the type you mention provide *computational upper bounds*.